# How to position progressIndicator to center in windows phone?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

I am newbie to windows phone development. 
I have created the progress indicator using following code .

```
        ProgressIndicator progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
        progressIndicator.IsVisible = true;
        progressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = true;          
        SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, progressIndicator);
```

It is working fine. But it is coming in the top of display. I want to place  it in  center of display. How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom progress bar.  That way you can define the control template as you would like.  The following link should get you started:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg442303(v=vs.105).aspx

or you can override the control template of the standard ProgressIndicator, though I believe the performance of this control is quite poor.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Phone SDK has an progress bar control which can be placed into any place of the page. But this control has weak performance to avoid this weakness you should use PerformanceProgressBar control from the [Silverlight for Windows Phone](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291)